# How to show an image near the mouse when click on the row

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

My code looks like that

```
public ImageIcon pictures[]=new ImageIcon[100];
jLabel10.setIcon(pictures[jTable1.getSelectedRow()]);  
jLabel10.setLocation(getMousePosition().x,getMousePosition().y);
```

How can I show an image near the mouse pointer on click event (I mean in the jTable)?

Answer (score 2):

Make a default configuration of your labels, let's say you have 9 labels in a 3x3 table and 9 image paths for these labels:

```
JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[3][3];
String[][] paths = new String[3][3];
```

In your MouseListener implementation you can append some text to the clicked label to display images:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
       int row = jTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
       int col = jTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
       // Assuming you have initialized the labels array and paths array.
       labels[row][col].setText(labels[row][col].getText() 
                                + "<html><img src=\""
                                + YourClass.class.getResource(paths[row][col])
                                + "\">);        
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to show this image near the mouse.did you notice that problem?

Comment: By "near the mouse" do you mean something like tooltip? if it is so, edit your question that you want a tooltip-like thing that will show the label images when you hover on the label, not "click". ok? then i will change my answer in that way working for your question.